# Set the max height of one child div as the height of another child of the same parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The div structure is -

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left float-start"></div>
    <div class="right float-end overflow-y"></div>
<div>
```

Now,

1. For the left child -

   - the height should be based on dynamic content
   - displayed entirely with no overflow scroll
2. For the right child -

   - height is also based on dynamic content but
   - max height should be the height of the left child
   - set to overflow-y scroll and so it's never longer than the left child but can be shorter

How do i do this only using css?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score -1):

@Ashley you can use this css for this problem.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left float-start"></div>
    <div class="right float-end overflow-y"></div>
<div>
```

// For equal height of the div
CSS:-

```
.parent {display: flex;}
```

/***** for mobile view *****/

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {.parent { flex-wrap: wrap;}}
```

// this is break the column according to the width of the div

Comment: thank you for responding! but this doesn't base the height of the right child on the left child. there are cases where the right child has more content, but I don't want the right child to be longer than the left if that makes sense

Comment: @Ashley then we have to use jquery not only css will help

Comment: @Ashley please check this "https://jsfiddle.net/wqexbnap/2/" this will help